# Chat messages space from bottom of page

Tags: html, css, ejs

I am trying to create some space between the last message in the chat and the bottom of the page so that my textarea isn't overlapping the last message. Both divs are in the same parent container.  Any best practice ideas here?

```
<div class="prevChatBox">
    <!-- previous chats boxes -->
    <ul id="chats"></ul>
</div>

<div class="chatDiv">
    <textarea id="chatInput" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Type your message here!"></textarea>
    <button type="button" id="messageSubmit">
        Submit
    </button>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If both div are in the same parent, then I assume that you are using `position: absolute` and `bottom: FOOpx` in your **chatDiv** now.
In this case, you can set `padding-bottom: BARpx` to your **prevChatBox**

In case, you don't intend to use `position: absolute` here, You should check again, because in normal case **chatDiv** will not overlap your **prevChatbox**

**Can you use snippet code feature of stackoverflow to post your question**